# HAProxy 443 gives Connection Error During SSL Handshake

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I recently setup a haproxy to route to multiple backends. I have a frontend for 443 and 4443 with the same configuration and pointing to the same backend. However, I am unable to connect to 443.

**HAProxy Config**

```
frontend main_web
    bind *:4443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/web.net.pem
    log-format "%ci:%cp\ [%tr]\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta\ %ST\ %B\ %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ %hr\ %hs\ %{+Q}r"
    timeout client 60000
    option logasap
    option httplog 
    log global
    mode http
    default_backend app-webserver

frontend main_https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/web.net.pem
    log-format "%ci:%cp\ [%tr]\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %TR/%Tw/%Tc/%Tr/%Ta\ %ST\ %B\ %CC\ %CS\ %tsc\ %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq\ %hr\ %hs\ %{+Q}r"
    timeout client 60000
    option logasap
    option httplog 
    log global
    mode http
    default_backend app-webserver
```

**haproxy -vv**

```
HA-Proxy version 2.0.13 2020/02/13 - https://haproxy.org/
Build options :
  TARGET  = linux-glibc
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-old-style-declaration -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wtype-limits
  OPTIONS = USE_OPENSSL=1

Feature list : +EPOLL -KQUEUE -MY_EPOLL -MY_SPLICE +NETFILTER -PCRE -PCRE_JIT -PCRE2 -PCRE2_JIT +POLL -PRIVATE_CACHE +THREAD -PTHREAD_PSHARED -REGPARM -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +TPROXY +LINUX_TPROXY +LINUX_SPLICE +LIBCRYPT +CRYPT_H -VSYSCALL +GETADDRINFO +OPENSSL -LUA +FUTEX +ACCEPT4 -MY_ACCEPT4 -ZLIB -SLZ +CPU_AFFINITY +TFO +NS +DL +RT -DEVICEATLAS -51DEGREES -WURFL -SYSTEMD -OBSOLETE_LINKER +PRCTL +THREAD_DUMP -EVPORTS

Default settings :
  bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Built with multi-threading support (MAX_THREADS=64, default=2).
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports : SSLv3 TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
Built with network namespace support.
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
Built without compression support (neither USE_ZLIB nor USE_SLZ are set).
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity")
Built without PCRE or PCRE2 support (using libc's regex instead)
Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.

Available multiplexer protocols :
(protocols marked as <default> cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
              h2 : mode=HTX        side=FE|BE     mux=H2
              h2 : mode=HTTP       side=FE        mux=H2
       <default> : mode=HTX        side=FE|BE     mux=H1
       <default> : mode=TCP|HTTP   side=FE|BE     mux=PASS

Available services : none

Available filters :
    [SPOE] spoe
    [COMP] compression
    [CACHE] cache
    [TRACE] trace
```

**openssl s_client -connect web.net:443 -servername web.net**

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1589722937
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

**openssl s_client -connect web.net:4443 -servername web.net**

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = web.net
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=web.net
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFmjCCBIKgAwIBAgIQD3fKJWSyq1Az+UBaqwMxdjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBu
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMS0wKwYDVQQDEyRFbmNyeXB0aW9uIEV2ZXJ5d2hlcmUg
RFYgVExTIENBIC0gRzEwHhcNMjAwNTA2MDAwMDAwWhcNMjEwNTA2MTIwMDAwWjAZ
MRcwFQYDVQQDEw5vbmVjaGF0Lm5ldC5jbjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEP
ADCCAQoCggEBAJsCvmMYYkU+g9D4VsD+9x3uP48cThL5g6JyLfEQJuXlSuU9phej
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=web.net
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4263 bytes and written 345 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 54BDC38DCD0A9279A171928B2D2808D87DAF54E1043D478F19F416DBD6ADBA10
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BFF1322A89D44278761C283D083D6307C71A557A0FF299B158DBA4C69E7F81E87958CBAF6E5DEAB36D0799FAFD3D784F
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 36 ba 3e 06 ae 02 86 d2-fa 6c df e9 74 5c 63 2a   6.>......l..t\c*
    0010 - 73 49 1d 4e 0f 3c a5 29-46 e5 9b 1c ec 6f b8 f5   sI.N.<.)F....o..
    0020 - f9 96 2e bf 2c 03 d1 b2-d0 23 32 cf 54 f3 4f 6d   ....,....#2.T.Om

    Start Time: 1589723432
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I am really quite lost in this. I have tried SSL passthrough as well by setting `mode tcp` in HAProxy but that did not help as well.

Any insights would be great! Thank you.

Comment: On which platform do you run haproxy? Some systems requiers that you allow access to privileged ports like 443. apparmor, selinux,...?

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar, Im running on Cent OS 7 with SELinux disabled. I ran this "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on" and it did not change anything as SELinux is already disabled.

Comment: does a `curl -v https://127.0.0.1/` work?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work.

* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

Comment: A yes you will need to add `-k` `curl -v -k https://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: Hi, Yes the page loads with -k. Does that determine anything?

Comment: Yes this means that haproxy works and your problem is from external access. Do you have any firewall on the machine or in front of the server?

Comment: I am using firewalld but I have already opened 443 so that why I am able to access via https:// port but not by https:// domain. Its a weird issue but I still cannot figure it out.